# How do I make my excel spreadsheet take an un-organized column and group it into several small lists with a formula?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, spreadsheet

So I'm trying to find a formula to make my Excel spreadsheet take a very un-ordered list(Column B), and sort of compress it into several ordered lists automatically.

```
     Current Example         Desired Outcome 
     A      B              A      B
1: John - Apple       1: John - Apple   --------
2:                    2:      - Orange   *Search|
3:      - Orange      3:                  range |
4:                    4:                ________   
5: Nate               5: Nate - Apple   --------
6:      - Apple       6:      - Orange   *Search|    
7:                    7:      - Berry     range |    
8:      -Orange       8:                        |
9:      -Berry        9:                ________|
```

I need the things in Column A to stay where they are. And for column B to be ordered so that; from B1:B4 and B5:B9 etc. is in a list next to the A column values without spaces until the next list.

This is only one small piece of the whole spreadsheet and the cell locations and values are different than the example. And both of these columns are auto filled with formulas based on the rest of the spreadsheet, and data that is put in. If your interested the current formula in the B column looks like this: =IF(J3="","", IF(J3=0,D3, ""))  That is how the info For Column B is generated. Now I just need it to order the information like the above example.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Just make sure column A contains repeating data and is not left blank. 
Then sort by columns a and B

To fix column A data,

Insert a blank column and shunt B over.

Then do this
(assuming you have a header row, and data starts on row 2, otherwise B1=A1 etc..):

B2=A2

B3=IF(ISBLANK(A3),B2,A3)

B4=IF(ISBLANK(A4),B3,A4)

etc,

You can copy/paste the formula for B4 onwards from B3.

Then do a copy/paste special of values on column B over itself.

Then you can delete column A

Then just sort by columns A and B combined.